# prime ng sidebar component header content not showing

Tags: html, angular, typescript, frontend, primeng

Trying to add header in prime ng sidebar component but its not working

```
<p-sidebar [(visible)]="visibleSidebar1">
   
  <ng-template p-Template="header">
    <p>"Header"</p>
  </ng-template>
My content goes here
</p-sidebar>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using pTemplate="header" instead of p-Template="header"

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `pTemplate` instead of `p-Template -`

```
pTemplate="header"
```

Answer (score 0):

in shared component i tried this and seems to be working
{{Header}}

```
<p-sidebar [(visible)]="visibleSidebar1"><app-shared-component></app-shared-component></p-sidebar>
```